# get selectedvalue of dropdownlist items added from javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net

Hi I have added some items to `asp:DropDownList` from javascript. Like this

```
 if (document.getElementById("<%=gdview.ClientID %>")!=null)
    {
    var rows = document.getElementById("<%=gdview.ClientID %>").getElementsByTagName('tr');
    var cells = rows[1].getElementsByTagName('td');
  //alert(cells)
    i = 2;
    while (i < cells.length)
    {
        document.getElementById("<%=ddl_noofCols.ClientID %>").options[i] = new Option(i + 1, i);
        i++;
           }
    document.getElementById("<%=ddl_noofCols.ClientID %>").options[2].selected =true;
    alert(document.getElementById("<%=ddl_noofCols.ClientID %>").options[2].text);
    }
```

here gdview is gridview. no of columns of gridview are added to dropdownlist 
default is `options[2]` is selected. I cannot the get selecteditem/selectedvalue using `ddl_noofCols.SelectedValue` which returns null.

How can I get the selectedvalue.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You may want something like:

```
var table = document.getElementById("<%=gdview.ClientID %>");
var select = document.getElementById("<%=ddl_noofCols.ClientID %>");
var cells;

if (table) {
    cells = table.rows[1].cells;

    for  (var i=2, iLen=cells.length; i<iLen; i++) {
        select.options[i] = new Option(i + 1, i);
    }
    select.options[2].selected = true;
    alert(select.options[2].text);

    // To get the current value of the select, 
    // use the value property:
    alert(select.value);
}
```

The value of the currently selected option is available as *select.value*. If the selected option has no value attribute or property, then the value of the *text* property is returned except in IE 8 and lower, where you must use something like:

```
var value = select.value;

if (!value) {
    value = select.options[select.selectedIndex].text;
}
```

Comment: I want to get the selected value in the code-behind as I mentioned as `ddl_noofCols.SelectedValue`